# Navigate from jetpack compose activity to xml activity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

every time i try to navigate from a jetpack compose activity to an xml activity the app crashes and i get this error : Process: Sending signal. PID: 4409 SIG: 9

i am confused about what to do in order to solve the problem

Comment: Please provide some code - how you create the Intent and how you call startActivity.